# Facebook #Hashtag: How to retrive feed by Hastags?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

As we can get feeds of specific user or fan page, I wanted to know that how can I get feeds from specific `Hashtag` like in twitter by `fql` or `Graph API` ?

I am using `Facebook SDK 3.5.2`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, searching specific posts by hashtags is currently unavailable.
You can still find posts regarding a #hashtag querying a user's **stream** for a specific message:

```
SELECT message 
FROM stream 
WHERE 
(source_id IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me()) OR source_id=me()  )
AND strpos(lower(message),lower('#hashtag')) >=0
```

Comment: such FQL is deprecated now