# Does anyone know how to fetch photo using hashtag in facebook?

Tags: php, photo, hashtag

I would like to fetch picture with a particular hashtag for example #love from facebook, is it available now?

Comment: Related Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17385971/1465973